# Trying to interact with a Website "synchronously" using javascript in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, java, forms, android-webview

I'm trying to interact with a Website "synchronously" (javascript events when submit buttons are clicked) in order to get a textField value. This textField doesn't exist in the first place. It is generated when the user clicks on a submit button from a HTML form (2 buttons actually : first one : **Id = "ColumnLeft_ADD_BTN_ID"**, second one : **Id = "ColumnLeft_GET_BTN_ID"**).
When I simulate a click with Javascript, the textField doesn't appear. I get  this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" because the textField doesn't exist.

I've tried HTMLUnit but I couldn't make it work with Android. I turned to Android WebView.
Here's my code :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl(url);
final String js = "(function() { " +
            "document.getElementById('ColumnLeft_RES_TB_ID').value='" + group + "';" +
            "document.getElementById('ColumnLeft_ADD_BTN_ID').click();" +
            "document.getElementById('ColumnLeft_GET_BTN_ID').click();" +
            "return document.getElementById('ColumnLeft_FEED_URL_TB_ID').value; " +
            "})();";
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
                view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
                        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(s));

                        // Must set lenient to parse single values
                        reader.setLenient(true);

                        try {
                            if(reader.peek() != JsonToken.NULL) {
                                if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                                    String msg = reader.nextString();
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", "msg : " + msg);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "MainActivity: IOException", e);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                reader.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // NOOP
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```